# Name of the dropdown panel

Tags: jquery, css

May I know what kind of drop down panel is this.?
[Link](http://www.pc-specs.com/pc-builder/index.php?id=135242&cpu=Intel_Core_i7-4770S_4-Core_3.1GHz&graphics=AMD_Radeon_R9_270_Gigabyte_WindForce_2X_OC_Edition&ram=16GB)

It is on the Optimum Home PC List. When you click one item, it will drop down the other Contents

I want to do it but I don't know what it's called, so that I can search for tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a custom made but a simple concept. Have a div with as a "heading" and a subsecuent with details. Use jQuery for detect event and find div to show with details. I made this simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/o3odoq7j/) in order to simplify the concept:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".toggle div:not('.noaction')").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle();
});

$(".anoterAction").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $parent=$("#"+$(this).attr('data-parent'));
    $parent.addClass('dontOpen');
    alert("another action!");


});
```

});

HTML

```
<div class="toggle" id="1">
<div>Just one row</div>
<div>Just another one row</div>
<div class="noaction"><a class="anoterAction"  data-parent="1" href="">Maybe a link that make another action!</a></div>
</div>
<div class="details">
<p>You can put all details here</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle" id="2">
<div>Just one row</div>
<div>Just another one row</div>
<div><a class="anoterAction" href="">Maybe a link that make another action!</a></div>
</div>
<div class="details">
<p>Other detail for other row</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.details
{
    display:none;
    border:1px solid #444;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    border-top:none;
    padding:20px;
}

.toggle
{
   display:block;
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   background: #eee;
   margin-top: 10px;
   padding:10px;
}

.toggle div
{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can try using MNMENU JQUERY DROPDOWN MENU PLUGIN which you can find in jquery.com or you can use pure css to generate that that kind of drop down